# Selecionando intervalos diferentes em um dataframe gigante no RStudio

Tags: python, r, big-data

Tenho um CSV **muito** grande com datas de várias ações e seus preços de fechamento, impossível utilizar o Excel.

O nome da ação está na mesma coluna da data e só aparece no início da série, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho conhecimento limitado em R e estou precisando de alguma function que me ajude a fazer essa leitura de intervalo.

OBS: O nome da ação está sempre entre parênteses: `(AÇÃO X)`

Comment: Quais são os nomes das colunas no seu csv, @Filipe?

Comment: No meu original (como falei acima, o nome da ação está na coluna "Data"):

Data ; Preço



Como eu gostaria:

Data ; Preço ; Ação

Comment: Eu respondi abaixo usando nomes genéricos para as colunas, mas você pode alterar, no caso o `c0` viraria o `Data`:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348663/132077

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira de fazer isso, seria (não sei se é a mais eficiente, mas é possível e funciona):

1. Saber onde estão os separadores do seu `DataFrame`, ou seja, quais linhas que possuem valores de texto vazio para cada uma das colunas, e salvar os index em uma lista
2. Rodar para cada index da lista `linhasVazias` e separar as Series que você possui em subséries de acordo com o index (cada subsérie contendo uma Ação)
3. Reformatar esse `DataFrame` contendo a subsérie resultante no novo formato
4. Salvando no df final, que vai receber as novas informações

Aqui o código onde faço essas operações:

```
linhasVazias = df[(df['c0'] == "") & (df['c1'] == "") ].index.tolist()

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'c0': [], 'c1': [], 'c2': []})
anterior = -1

for i in linhasVazias:
    # Separa a série relacionada
    temp = df[anterior+1 : i]

    # Cria a nova coluna com o nome da ação
    temp['c2'] = temp.iloc[0][0]

    # Remove a primeira linha, com o nome da ação
    temp = temp.drop([anterior+1], axis = 0)

    # Salva no novo dataFrame as linhas relacionadas
    df_final = df_final.append(temp)
    anterior = i

# Reseta os index no novo DataFrame, excluindo a coluna dos valores antigos
df_final = df_final.reset_index(drop = True)
```

*OBS:*
- aqui usei "c0", "c1" e "c2" para o nome das colunas
- para o caso seu, que possui um DF muito grande, não sei se o processamento vai ser eficiente, mas vale o teste

Comment: @Filipe, veja se funciona para você, e em caso positivo, marque minha resposta como a correta, por favor.